# DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. ioni 2 adding platform in android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

while adding platform in ionic 2 getting following error

```
(node:5360) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
    block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
     id: 1)
    (node:5360) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
    cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
     Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Is there anything else that you are missing in that error message that might shed more light on the source?

Answer (score 0):

thats could be bacause there are node modules outdated. 
You can try running

```
ionic doctor check
```

in your project root folder, thats would fix all the problems.

Doc:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/doctor/check/